# How much disk space needed for 100GB of DBs?

Tags: sql-server, migration, disk-space

Hard to explain in the title, but I'm planning a migration from SQL Server 2000 databases to SQL Server 2008 R2.  The databases are under 100GB total space, but this is only with the Simple recovery model.  I'd like to migrate, then change to full recovery model.

So, my question is: how much disk space will I need?  Obviously I know there is some amount of opinion here, but what are the common ways of calculating this?

Comment: It all depends on how often you plan on taking transaction log backups combined with how many logged transactions are happening between backups.

Comment: [My database is X GB, how big should my log be?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2011/03/01/my-database-is-x-gb-how-big-should-my-log-be.aspx)

Comment: And whether you are placing the backups and log backups on the same set of disks or elsewhere - usually you provision those separately, and even if you back up locally and then move off, the local requirement will be less but still vary depending on database growth and log activity. Still, knowing only the size of your databases and nothing about the activity, the only possible answer is "it depends."

Comment: @ThomasStringer -Any suggestions on how I can estimate that?

Comment: @AaronBertrand -Any suggestions how to get numbers for activity?  How do I measure it?

Comment: A good start would be to turn on full on your current system and see what the log file sizes are given a typical workload cycle and what your log frequency will likely be on the new system.